# Fatal Exception using Chaquopy on Android Studio

Tags: android, chaquopy

This is my code for a image recognition and voice recognition app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView micicon;
ImageView camicon;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    micicon = findViewById(R.id.micicon);
    camicon = findViewById(R.id.cameraicon);

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                }, 100);
    }

    camicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }
    });

    micicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //python voice
            Intent voice = new Intent();
            if(!Python.isStarted()){
                Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(getApplicationContext()));
            }

            Python py = Python.getInstance();

            PyObject pyf = py.getModule("voice").callAttr("voicerun");
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        Bitmap captureImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

}

When I build the app, there is no problem with it. But when I try to run the app and use the mic icon to use the python script, it shows this error, and it crashes. The python file runs perfectly on VSCode.

```
2020-05-05 03:10:41.978 20585-20585/com.example.medicator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.medicator, PID: 20585
com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'voice'
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:973)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._gcd_import(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014)
    at <python>.importlib.import_module(__init__.py:127)
    at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_Python_getModule(chaquopy_java.pyx:153)
    at com.chaquo.python.Python.getModule(Native Method)
    at com.example.medicator.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

How to fix this problem? I am using Chaquopy 7.0.2. I already installed the Python Community Plugin in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If `voice` is a module of your own, then you should put it in src/main/python as described in the [documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#source-code). Here's a [simple example](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-console/).

Or if it's from a third-party library, install it in your build.gradle file using the syntax described in the [documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#requirements).